# All boundary points of a Jordan Domain are simple

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, geometry, complex-geometry, curves

I have tried many things but I have not succeeded. I am trying to find a topological proof of the fact that all boundary points of a simply connected, bounded Jordan Domain (i.e, the bounded interior of a Jordan curve) are simple boundary points. Is there some proof that does not use the Caratheodory extension theorem?

The definition of simple boundary point can be found in https://planetmath.org/simpleboundarypoint.

From what I have seen, it would be enough to show that every such Jordan Domain is locally connected. Is that true?

Comment: What about using the Jordan curve theorem instead as you need topological homeomorphisms only

Comment: How would it help the solution? I already know my Domain is bounded and has a Jordan Curve as boundary, what extra info would Jordan's theorem give?

Comment: The fact that there  is a topological  homeomorphism between the interior and the unit disc which extends the original curve homeomorphism

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. Thanks a lot, that obviously would solve the problem. Could you send a link or a reference to that result, though? I know one using Caratheodory's Theorem, but that is exactly what I want to prove.

Comment: Check jordan schoenflies theorem on Wikipedia; the point of caratheodory imho is that any conformal map extends